# For which $c$ do the surfaces $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2+c=z$ intersect tangentially? Orthogonally?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, surfaces

Consider the following two surfaces:
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \tag{1}$$
$$x^2 + y^2 + c\phantom{^2} = z \tag{2}$$

For which values of $c$ are they (a) mutually tangent at all their points of intersections? (b) Orthogonal at all their points of intersection?

*Source: Based on Shifrin's Multivariable Mathematics.*

---

My work so far:

**Solution:**

(a) is met if $c < -5/4$ (trivially), $c > 1$ (trivially), or $c = -5/4$ (at $z = -1/2$).
(b) is met if $c < -5/4$ (trivially), $c > 1$ (trivially), $c = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{17}}{8}$ (at $z = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{17}}{4}$), or $c = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{17}}{8}$ (at $z = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{17}}{4}$).

**Proof:**

As shown in [my previous question about these surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743709/for-which-values-of-c-are-there-solutions-to-the-system-of-equations-x2-y), these two surfaces intersect [iff $c \in [-5/4, 1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743709/for-which-values-of-c-are-there-solutions-to-the-system-of-equations-x2-y).  We therefore have the trivial solution: If $c \notin [-5/4, 1]$, both conditions are met.

For $c \in [-5/4, 1]$, we look at their Jacobians:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2x & 2y & 2z \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}2x & 2y & -1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

If these are equal, the tangent planes are parallel.  If these are equal at a point of intersection, the intersection is therefore tangential.  These are equal iff $2z = -1$, so $z = -1/2$ and $c = -5/4$.

If their dot product is zero, the tangent planes are orthogonal; if the dot product is zero at a point of intersection, the intersection is orthogonal.  This happens iff at the point of intersection $$4(x^2 + y^2) -2z = 0$$ so $z = 2c$.  The rest follows from the quadratic equation.

**Question:** The case $c = 1, z = 1$ would seem geometrically to be tangential, but the Jacobians seem to show the planes *not* being tangential there.

Comment: Why did you ask the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743709/for-which-values-of-c-are-there-solutions-to-the-system-of-equations-x2-y) twice? This doesn't seem sufficiently different that it couldn't have been edited into your original question, unless you have a good reason I'm not following.

Comment: @NinadMunshi The other question asks: "Where do they intersect?". This question asks: "Given that they intersect in certain places, is that intersection tangential? Orthogonal? Or neither?".  This question (only) requires calculus and Jacobians - the other can be done using pure algebra.  Note my work here uses the Jacobians to determine tangentiality and orthogonality, but leaves off with an unsolved problem.  Of course the questions are related, but math.SE encourages asking only one question per post.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. In that case I don't follow your bolded question at the end. Why do believe that to be the situation with $c=z=1$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi At $(0,0,1)$, the Jacobians indicate that the sphere's tangent plane is $0x + 0y + 2z = 2$ or $z =1$, but the paraboloid's tangent plane is $0x + 0y -1 = -1$ - or do I have that wrong (that doesn't seem like a plane)? It would seem to me that, unlike a cone, a paraboloid is flat enough at its vertex to have a tangent plane that it sits on, which should be the same as that of the sphere.  But I can't get the Jacobians to show that.  Perhaps I'm confused as to how to test if tangent planes are parallel by comparing Jacobians.

Comment: Your criteria for parallel planes is incorrect. The normal vectors don't need to be *equal* - they must be *scalar multiples* of each other. From your Jacobians, one vector is $(0,0,2)$ and the other is $(0,0,-1)$. Those look like scalar multiples to me. Also your second tangent plane equation is missing a $z$.

Answer (score 1):

From

$$
\cases{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\\
x^2 + y^2 + c = z}
$$

due to symmetry we have

$$
\cases{
f(y,z) = y^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0\\
g(y,z) = y^2 -z + c = 0}\ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

After substituting $z = y^2+c$ into the first equation we have

$$
p(y)=y^2+(y^2+c)^2-1 = (y-r)^2(c_1 y^2+c_2 y+c_3)
$$

which states that at tangency $p(y)$ should have a double root. Now equating for all $y$ we have

$$
\cases{
c^2-c_3 r^2-1=0\\
2 c_3 r-c_2 r^2=0\\
2 c-c_1 r^2+2 c_2 r-c_3+1=0\\
2 c_1r-c_2=0\\
1-c_1=0
}
$$

with solutions

$$
\left[
\matrix{
c & r & c_1 & c_2 & c_3\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 &  1  & 0   & 3  \\
-\frac 54 & -\frac{\sqrt {3}}{2}& 1 &-\sqrt{3}&\frac 34\\
-\frac 54 & \frac{\sqrt {3}}{2}& 1 &\sqrt{3}&\frac 34
}
\right]
$$

Now from

$$
\cases{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\\
x^2 + y^2 - \frac 54 = z}\Rightarrow x^2+y^2=\frac 34
$$

The tangency is verified along the circle $x^2+y^2=\frac 34, z = -\frac 12$ so there are infinite common tangent planes.  Attached the two tangent surfaces at the black circle. At the top, the tangency for $c=1$ and at the botton for $c=-1$.

[image]

To determine the normal intersection we proceed as follows. From $(1)$

$$
\cases{
\nabla f = (y,z)\\
\nabla g = (2y,-1)
}
$$

so the orthogonality condition is $\nabla f\times \nabla g  = 2y^2-z = 0$ and now solving for $y,z,c$

$$
\cases{
y^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0\\
y^2 -z + c = 0\\
2y^2-z = 0
}
$$

we obtain

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
c & y & z\\
 \frac{1}{8} \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right) & -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right)} & \frac{1}{4}
   \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right) \\
 \frac{1}{8} \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right) & \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right)} & \frac{1}{4}
   \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

now with $c =  \frac{1}{8} \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right)$ we have

[image]

Comment: $x^2+y^2= c-z$ should be $x^2+y^2= z-c$

Comment: This approach miss the solution $c=1$.

Comment: Your first attempt used "tangency implies a double root", yet that reasoning miss the solution $c=1$. Now you have found 2 solutions using the same "tangency implies a double root" argument. How do you know this time you didn't miss another solution? (I know that's not the case, but that's not the point).

Comment: Because the first time I went with a reduced expression. Now this one uses symmetry and covers all possibilities.

Comment: Then why you didn't find $c=-1$? For that case the surfaces are also tangent at $(0,0,-1)$. (This case needs to be treated separately to discard it because although the surfaces are tangent at that point, they also intersects in other points non-tangentially).

Comment: I found it but was distracted with $c= 1$ so I forgot to include it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! 1. How are you replacing $x^2 + y^2$ with just $y^2$? Are you limiting the exploration to the $x = 0$ plane, since similar results will be true elsewhere? Or are you introducing a new $y$ such that $y_{new}^2 = x^2 + y_{old}^2$? 2. What about my solution $c = (-1 - \sqrt{17})/8$ - I don't see it here. If it's incorrect, where is my mistake?

Comment: You are welcome. First, the $z$ axis is a symmetry axis so we can choose  as suitable any plane that contains it. Second. $c = -(1+\sqrt{17})/8$ is not a solution to the problem. I didn't follow your solution method because I was interested in a method using calculus at the minimum.